# No matching version found for scheduler@^0.13.4

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

There is a previous issue with react installing scheduler
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13693

Yesterday I could `npm install`. Today with no changes to package.json I see this:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for scheduler@^0.13.4
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

`scheduler` seems to have `0.13.4` https://www.npmjs.com/package/scheduler but I cannot install this module separately. I can however install `0.13.3` separately. It also looks like `0.13.4` was Published 16 hours ago.

I'm using react `16.6.1`

Is anyone else experiencing this? Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work,

Maybe you are behind/pointing to a private repository or corporate-proxy repository?

```
dev npm install scheduler
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/user/dev/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/user/dev/package.json'
npm WARN dev No description
npm WARN dev No repository field.
npm WARN dev No README data
npm WARN dev No license field.

+ scheduler@0.13.4
added 4 packages from 3 contributors and audited 4 packages in 1.66s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Comment: This was it! :face palm:

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. What was the solution for this?

Comment: @KaushikRamachandran The issue, most likely, was/is that your npm mirror is lagging behind. The issue should resolve itself in a couple of hours or a day.